# TypeError: Can only call Blob.slice on instances of Blob

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, swagger

When I use **swagger UI** to upload a file, I get this error message:

`console log error: TypeError: Can only call Blob.slice on instances of Blob`

[image]

Comment: [Swagger UI bug tracker](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues) is probably a better place for issues like this.